# 2009 Toyota Camry's brand new OEM power window master switch won't control the drivers window

Tags: electrical, toyota, camry, switches

Why would the driver's side window operate perfect with the original master switch but not work when I install a new power window master switch?

I purchased 2 new aftermarket power window master switches and 1 OEM switch. All three of the switches wouldn't control the driver's side window but every other button worked great on all the switches.

Why does my original master switch control the driver's window but the new ones will not?

Comment: Does the old switch _still_ work?

Comment: Does the car have 1 or 2 switches that operates the drivers window (maybe one on the door and one on the centre console)?

Answer (score 1):

I have a 2000 Toyota Camry, and if I'm not mistaken the drivers window control setup is very much the same as on your car.

Some things you can rule out:

- It's not the window or the wiring to the window because the old switch still works.
- It's not just the aftermarket part because the new OEM part does it too.

Here is something you can try. The difference is clearly in one of the switches, and not the wiring. But, you might be able to fix it by modifying the wiring to match the new switch. To figure out what you would need to change, do the following:

- Take a Digital Volt Meter (DVM) and put it into the "Measure resistance" mode.
- Remove the plate from the door handle that contains the switch pack, which if you have replaced it you must have already done. Otherwise I would suggest looking on YouTube as there are lots of videos on how to remove Camry interior trim parts.
- Now, compare the old and new switches to see if there are any differences between them. What you are looking for is which contacts are connected when the switch is closed. You need to map this out for both the new and old switches, and then compare the maps. Don't forget to create the map for both directions of the switch.
- If the two map out the same, then I have no idea why the new one wouldn't work. But I'm betting that they are different somehow.

Comment: the systems are basically the same but in this case i wonder if OPs car had jam protection if it does the wiring/switches and pin outs are different.